# In constructor, why can't I replace this.state={} with this.state.stateName = xxx

Tags: reactjs

I am working on the FilterableProductTable example in the official docs.(https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

I'd like to know why my components cannot render when I set states like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state.onlyStocked = false;
    this.state.filteredText = '';
  }
```

but it is running when set it like:

```
    this.state = {
      onlyStocked : false,
      filteredText : '',
    }
```

Is this an asynchronous issue?

Comment: You can't do that. You should use `this.setState`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.state.onlyStocked = false;
```

This will work (in the constructor, not for changing the state later), but only if `this.state` exists. So if you want to use this style, you first need to create the object.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.state.onlyStocked = false;
    this.state.filteredText = '';
}
```